# When use TortoiseGit with cygwin. Commit error

Tags: git, encoding, cygwin, tortoisegit

I'm Korean. 
So we use Korean file name. But I use TortoiseGit with Cygwin. Commit error.
When I use TortoiseGit, This error Message. But I use Cygwin it will work.

This is error Message.

```
git.exe update-index [...]
/usr/bin/bash: /bin/git.exe update-index -- "새 텍스트 문서.txt": No such file or directory
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 127)
```

TortoiseGit Setting

General -> Git for Windows 
Git.exe Path : C:\cygwin\bin
(Git version 2.8.3)

Advanced 
CygwinHack true

Help Me~! Thank you

Comment: The cygwin git is known to have several issues - it also doesn't even pass the git test suite.

Comment: Please try to find out why you get "No such file or directory", e.g. using a tool like procmon. Do ASCII only filenames work?

Comment: Yes. When I use English filename It work.
Tortoisegit and cygwin
When I use Korean filename 
Tortoisegit not work. but Cygwin is work.

Comment: Does cygwin git also work then used from cmd?

Comment: K@DESKTOP-0QPP593 /cygdrive/c/Users/K/Desktop/tt
$ git commit -m "test"
[master (최상위-커밋) c7cc1f2] test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 "\354\203\210 \355\205\215\354\212\244\355\212\270 \353\254\270\354\204\234.txt"

Yes It work.

Comment: Cygwin bash != cmd. Please gbive the output of git add filename from Windows cmd.

Comment: Windows cmd git is not work. So I set path = C:\cygwin\bin
---------------------
C:\Users\K\Desktop\tt>git add .

C:\Users\K\Desktop\tt>git commit -m "test"
[master c7821ea] test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 "\354\203\210 \355\205\215\354\212\244\355\212\270 \353\254\270\354\204\234 - \353\263\265\354\202\254\353\263\270 (3).txt"

Comment: Sorry, but "add ." won't trigger a possible issue. You have to pass the full filename. The issue in TortoiseGit is not commit, but passing thenon-ASCII filename to Cygwin git. Therefore, please test whether this is possible from Windows cmd.

Comment: C:\Users\H8055\Desktop\tt>git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        새 텍스트 문서.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

C:\Users\H8055\Desktop\tt>git add "새 텍스트 문서.txt"
fatal: pathspec '"새 텍스트 문서.txt"' did not match any files

------------------------------------------------------------
I set PATH = C:\cygwin\bin     and  doesn't work in Windows cmd.

Comment: OK, so the problem seems to be in cygwin with UTF16 conversion.

Comment: It means. One is UTF8 the other is UTF16???  Can i fixed it???

Comment: My windows encoding is 949
ex) C:\Users\H8055>chcp
활성 코드 페이지: 949

My Cygwin(Linux) encoding is "ko_KR.UTF-8"
ex) H8055 ~$ set 
...
LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8
....

How can i fix it? 
@MrTux

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm no cygwin expert. If you find a way on how to pass a korean encoded filename to git.exe I can try to code this into TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an incompatibility between the Windows world and the Cygwin world (in the sense of encoding): TortoiseGit calls `git.exe` in order to update the file. As you described in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609669/when-use-tortoisegit-with-cygwin-commit-error?noredirect=1#comment72375375_42609669) it also did not work for you from Windows cli.

I'm no cygwin export, but if you find a way on how to pass a korean encoded filename to git.exe from Windows cli I can try to code this into TortoiseGit.

PS: I strongly recommend not to use cygwin as cygwin git is known to be broken as it does not even pass the test suite (cf. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3040#issuecomment-94169001) - that's why Cygwin support is just experimental in TortoiseGit. Better use [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Have a nice day ; )